# Grabbing Information from Array PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have some information in a Joomla Database I need to loop through, and pull out certain information.

I can successfully loop through articles fine, but I cant get the information of from the [image]. I need to pull just the "image_intro":"image/banner_box.jpg" if possible just the "banner_box.jpg".

My code so far to loop through database.

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
                    //makes array
                    $newsitems[] = array(
                        'title' => $item->title,
                        'text'  => $item->introtext,
                        'image' => $item->images

                    );                  
                }
```

My out put printed.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Service 2
            [text] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conseteetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam monumy eirmod..<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">View more</a></p>
            [image] => {"image_intro":"images\/banner_box2.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Service 1 
            [text] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conseteetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam monumy eirmod..<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">View more</a></p>
            [image] => {"image_intro":"images\/banner_box1.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
        )

)
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$item->images is in json format, so you need to decode it

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $imgData = json_decode($item->images, true);

    // create array
    $newsitems[] = array(
        'title' => $item->title,
        'text'  => $item->introtext,
        'image' => $imgData['image_intro']
    );                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That data is encoded in `json` format. You need to decode it using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You code will look something like this (inside your loop):

`$images_data = json_decode($item->images);`

You can then access properties of the object like this: `$images_data->images_intro`.

Answer (score 2):

try with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), like:

```
$decoded = json_decode($newsitems[0]['image'], true); //make it array for later access
```